# R: What can not install package?

Tags: r

I have a problem for installing each package in R. for example When I type:

```
install.packages("rvest")
```

I see:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/farzad/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rvest’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
```

This is for installing all packages. What should I do?

Comment: Did you choose a mirror with `chooseCRANmirror()` or the RStudio or R.app GUI? Did you try more than one?

Comment: Also check what `.libPaths()` looks like. It should return a path to your package library.

Comment: try installing for example the package meta which is available for your R version